# Which graphics board my OS is using?

Tags: linux, graphics

Is there any way to specify which graphics chipset our OS should use? on machines with discrete GPU, when graphics driver installed linux will by default use GPU for UI but I want OS to use on-board graphics. Is there any way to do this? through BIOS?Xorg.conf?
Machine conf:
Linux 32bit
GPU: NVIDIA Tesla

Answer (score 1):

The on-board graphics card is disabled by the plugged in card. This is expected behaviour on most motherboards.

You can check if you see both cards using `lspci`. It'll show you one line per monitor output. There will be many lines of output because your system is loaded with devices connected to the PCI-bus, so you'll have to filter the GUI lines manually. That shouldn't be too hard though. Mine looks like this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

A single on board GPU (PCI address `00:02`) with two outputs (output `.0` and `.1`). I have no extra GPU in my system.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to plug a monitor into the port for the GPU you want to use, and don't plug a monitor into the port for the GPU you don't want to use. Then start the computer.

Comment: Only one VGA port is available that too connected to graphics card.

Comment: If the only port is on the motherboard than both should be in use. I have heard of a gpu or 2 that only provides a gpu and ram for hpc but most have there own monitor ports. If your motherboard has it's own graphics chip than it should also have it's own monitor ports. Unless you have a vga monitor and only a DVI port on the motherboard or graphics card only. In this case you might be able to find a dvi to vga adapter if your graphics card supports it. Check here... http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&N=-1&isNodeId=1&Description=dvi+to+vga&x=0&y=0